# Using Word2Vec in scikit-learn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to run the w2v on this sample of data

```
Statement              Label
Says the Annies List political group supports third-trimester abortions on demand.       FALSE
When did the decline of coal start? It started when natural gas took off that started to begin in (President George W.) Bushs administration.         TRUE
"Hillary Clinton agrees with John McCain ""by voting to give George Bush the benefit of the doubt on Iran."""     TRUE
Health care reform legislation is likely to mandate free sex change surgeries.    FALSE
The economic turnaround started at the end of my term.     TRUE
The Chicago Bears have had more starting quarterbacks in the last 10 years than the total number of tenured (UW) faculty fired during the last two decades.    TRUE
Jim Dunnam has not lived in the district he represents for years now.    FALSE
```

using the code provided in this GitHub folder (FeatureSelection.py):

https://github.com/nishitpatel01/Fake_News_Detection

I would like to include word2vec features in my Naive Bayes model.
First I considered X and y and used train_test_split:

```
X = df['Statement']
y = df['Label']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=40)

dataset = pd.concat([X_train, y_train], axis=1)
```

This is the code I am currently using:

```
#Using Word2Vec 
with open("glove.6B.50d.txt", "rb") as lines:
    w2v = {line.split()[0]: np.array(map(float, line.split()[1:]))
           for line in lines}

training_sentences = DataPrep.train_news['Statement']

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(training_sentences, size=100) # x be tokenized text
w2v = dict(zip(model.wv.index2word, model.wv.syn0))


class MeanEmbeddingVectorizer(object):
    def __init__(self, word2vec):
        self.word2vec = word2vec
        # if a text is empty we should return a vector of zeros
        # with the same dimensionality as all the other vectors
        self.dim = len(word2vec.itervalues().next())

    def fit(self, X, y): # what are X and y?
        return self

    def transform(self, X): # should it be training_sentences?
        return np.array([
            np.mean([self.word2vec[w] for w in words if w in self.word2vec]
                    or [np.zeros(self.dim)], axis=0)
            for words in X
        ])


"""
class TfidfEmbeddingVectorizer(object):
    def __init__(self, word2vec):
        self.word2vec = word2vec
        self.word2weight = None
        self.dim = len(word2vec.itervalues().next())
    def fit(self, X, y):
        tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=lambda x: x)
        tfidf.fit(X)
        # if a word was never seen - it must be at least as infrequent
        # as any of the known words - so the default idf is the max of 
        # known idf's
        max_idf = max(tfidf.idf_)
        self.word2weight = defaultdict(
            lambda: max_idf,
            [(w, tfidf.idf_[i]) for w, i in tfidf.vocabulary_.items()])
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return np.array([
                np.mean([self.word2vec[w] * self.word2weight[w]
                         for w in words if w in self.word2vec] or
                        [np.zeros(self.dim)], axis=0)
                for words in X
            ])
"""
```

and in classifier.py, I am running

```
nb_pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('NBCV',FeaturesSelection.w2v),
        ('nb_clf',MultinomialNB())])
```

However this is not working and I am getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-07045943a69c> in <module>
      2 nb_pipeline = Pipeline([
      3         ('NBCV',FeaturesSelection.w2v),
----> 4         ('nb_clf',MultinomialNB())])

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f
     75 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in __init__(self, steps, memory, verbose)
    112         self.memory = memory
    113         self.verbose = verbose
--> 114         self._validate_steps()
    115 
    116     def get_params(self, deep=True):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _validate_steps(self)
    160                                 "transformers and implement fit and transform "
    161                                 "or be the string 'passthrough' "
--> 162                                 "'%s' (type %s) doesn't" % (t, type(t)))
    163 
    164         # We allow last estimator to be None as an identity transformation

TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough' '{' ': array([-0.17019527,  0.32363772, -0.0770281 , -0.0278154 , -0.05182227, ....
```

I am using all the programs in that folder, so the code can be reproducible if you use them.

If you could explain me how to fix it and what other changes in the code would be necessary, it would be great. My goal is to compare models (naive bayes, random forest,...) with BoW, TF-IDF and Word2Vec.

Update:

After the answer below (from Ismail), I updated the code as follows:

```
class MeanEmbeddingVectorizer(object):
    def __init__(self, word2vec, size=100):
        self.word2vec = word2vec
        self.dim = size
```

and

```
#building Linear SVM classfier
svm_pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('svmCV',FeaturesSelection_W2V.MeanEmbeddingVectorizer(FeaturesSelection_W2V.w2v)),
        ('svm_clf',svm.LinearSVC())
        ])

svm_pipeline.fit(DataPrep.train_news['Statement'], DataPrep.train_news['Label'])
predicted_svm = svm_pipeline.predict(DataPrep.test_news['Statement'])
np.mean(predicted_svm == DataPrep.test_news['Label'])
```

However, I am still getting errors.

Comment: Can you think of a [reprex] that could be run start to finish? As for `if it is the right way to proceed within the FS program` substitution of sparse tfiidf with dense word2vec is definitely possible, but it won't get you any closer to identifying fake news, if it's your end goal. For that you need to extract facts and compare them against what you consider to be the truth.

Comment: when I uncomment model and w2v from the program in the link, I get this error: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string. So I think a step is missing and I would appreciate if someone can explain and show what is missing and how I can fix it.

Comment: For people to help you your error should be reproducible (you may think of updating your question with the error message BTW). And it should be minimal. This is why `because there was too much code`. Please consider [ask] and [reprex]. As an aside, your sklearn transformer should inherit from `BaseEstimator` and `TransformerMixin` to be runnable within sklearn pipeline but I do not know if it's enough for your program to execute because I do not know how to run it.

Comment: please see the update. I do not know how to improve the code. Everything is in the link (for a reproducible example). Thanks a lot

Comment: The error is pretty clear (but it's your last problem): every step of a `Pipeline` must implement `fit` and `transform`. Instead, you are passing a `dict`. But that's your last problem, since the code where you define `w2v` doesn't make any sense in the first place. You first load pretrained vectors in a dict. Then you define a Word2Vec model. Then you create a dictionary zipping the words in the Glove file with the untrained vectors of the model (.-.)

Comment: unfortunately I have not found yet a way to handle this problem so I am going to keep the question open in case you or someone else might help me to implement it with no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. MultinomialNB `FeaturesSelection.w2v` is a `dict` and it does not have `fit` or `fit_transform` functions. Also `MultinomialNB` needs non-negative values, so it doesn't work. So I decided to add a pre-processing stage to normalize negative values.

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

nb_pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('NBCV',MeanEmbeddingVectorizer(FeatureSelection.w2v)),
        ('nb_norm', MinMaxScaler()),
        ('nb_clf',MultinomialNB())
    ])
```

... instead of

```py
nb_pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('NBCV',FeatureSelection.w2v),
        ('nb_clf',MultinomialNB())
    ])
```

Step 2. I have got an error on `word2vec.itervalues().next()`. So I have decided to change dimension shape with predefined that is the same value of `Word2Vec`'s size.

```py
class MeanEmbeddingVectorizer(object):
    def __init__(self, word2vec, size=100):
        self.word2vec = word2vec
        self.dim = size
```

... instead of

```py
class MeanEmbeddingVectorizer(object):
    def __init__(self, word2vec):
        self.word2vec = word2vec
        self.dim = len(word2vec.itervalues().next())
```

Comment: Thanks Ismail. It does not work for me as I get this error: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'itervalues' which misses in self.dim.`I would have also one question about the word2vec in that code. Does it work for you using X in `model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(X, size=100)`
or you need to use `training_sentence` instead of X?

Comment: @LdM I have already tested and it is worked. However, accuracy is between 54% - 57%. I think you should add more stages to improve accuracy.

Comment: Sorry Ismail, but I am still getting the error AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'itervalues'. How did you fix it/handle it?

Comment: @LdM I added steps. Please look at the second step.

Comment: unfortunately the change has not fixed the issue. Now I am getting a new error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'transform' due to: nb_pipeline.fit(DataPrep.... ) This happens also for the other learners when I use FeatureSelection.MeanEmbeddingVectorizer(FeatureSelection.w2v)

Comment: @LdM can you update last changes, I can check what did you do?

Comment: please see the updated question. I have tried with other learners. I used the parts you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: @LdM I mentioned that `MultinomialNB` is not working for negative values. I have updated my answer with adding `MinMaxScaler` to normalize values 0 to 1. Please follow that solution for `MultinomialNB` pipeline.

Comment: Still getting the same error. I think there is a problem with DataPrep. Have you changed anything there? I know you mentioned the issue with NB so I have tried with a different learner (still in the link I shared) and it gives me the same error. I think there is a problem with DataPrep at this point

Comment: @LdM There are some errors like `SGDClassifier` `n_iter` is not recognised, I have replaced with `max_iter`. And remove `metrics.` package name on some lines. Also, there are lots of warnings. I executed successfully with changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226809/discussion-between-ldm-and-smail-durmaz).